# flexbox fill remaining window height not working

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make a layout with flexbox that will have two rows.

Neither of the rows will have fixed heights.

The first row is smaller and contains a logo.

The second row has two columns which must fill the remaining height of the screen.

Is this even possible with flexbox?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.header {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1.85185vh 4.16667vw;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 9vmin;
}
.header .right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: 4.16667vw;
  color: #191919;
  font-size: 3.5vmin;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.header img {
  height: 100%;
}
.main-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.columns-wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
.column-left,
.column-right {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
}
.column-left {
  background: red;
}
.column-right {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-wrapper">

  <header class="header" role="banner">
    <img src="http://img.logospectrum.com/dec/dummy-logo.jpg" alt="Logo">
    <div class="right">
      aaaaa
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="columns-wrapper">
    <div class="column-left">
      <div class="column-inner">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column-right">bbb</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/riogrande/pen/RGboox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the `.main-wrapper` a flex container in column-direction.

This will stack the children (`header` and `.columns-wrapper`) in two rows.

For `.columns-wrapper` to consume all remaining space in the container, apply `flex: 1`.

[revised codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GjKARZ)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.header {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1.85185vh 4.16667vw;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 9vmin;
}
.header .right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: 4.16667vw;
  color: #191919;
  font-size: 3.5vmin;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.header img {
  height: 100%;
}
.main-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;              /* NEW */
  flex-direction: column;     /* NEW */
}
.columns-wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;                   /* NEW */
}
.column-left,
.column-right {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
}
.column-left {
  background: red;
}
.column-right {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-wrapper">

  <header class="header" role="banner">
    <img src="http://img.logospectrum.com/dec/dummy-logo.jpg" alt="Logo">
    <div class="right">
      aaaaa
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="columns-wrapper">
    <div class="column-left">
      <div class="column-inner">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column-right">bbb</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, by adding to main-wrapper :

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

and by :

```
header {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.columns-wrapper {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

`1 1 auto` tells the columns-wrapper to stretch
while `0 0 auto` tells the header to not expand and keep its normal size.

see http://codepen.io/dievardump/pen/WGZRbv

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
min-height: 100%;
```

to .columns-wrapper

```
.columns-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: this will add a scroll because it won't take the remaining space but have a size of 100%. If you add the header size, the scroll appears